# Prevent outward SMS Text Messages

Tags: lumia, sms, nokia-lumia-525

I have a Lumia 525 running Cyan. Is there any way to bar all apps or the system to send outgoing SMSs. Or atleast ask for a password/PIN or permission before any SMS is sent?

EDIT: The reason behind the question. Few months back, I had gone out of the country with international roaming activated. My phone was an Android. In my next bill, I got one SMS sent from my phone everyday I was carrying it out the country, none of which I sent. I could never discover which App or anything else sent it.

Now I am going out of the country again & I don't want my Windows Phone to send any text messages while I am there.

Comment: Apps and the OS cannot send SMS without user interaction, so do you mean if you've given your unlocked phone to a friend?

Comment: @RowlandShaw - Updated the question. Are you sure apps cannot send messages without permission?

Answer (score 4):

Apps and the OS cannot send SMS without user interaction - the only thing an app can do is [compose an SMS for you](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh394005(v=vs.105).aspx), but it is up to the user to actually press send. I understand that this was a design choice taken by the developers to avoid exactly the bill shock that you experienced using your Android phone previously.

Comment: The most important bit of information is in the first paragraph: "**The message is not sent until the user presses the send button.**"